# How to use multiple languages in a VS Code notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code now has Notebooks, which are similar to Jupyter Notebooks. Within a given notebook each cell runs code based on the language selected for that cell.  Is it possible to write a function in C# in the first cell and then reference the first cells function in another cell that has a different language?

Cell1 (C#):

```
public void Printx() { Console.WriteLine("Name: " + Name); }
```

Cell2 (F# referencing the C# code in Cell1):

```
let prnt = Printx
```